# What is the efficiency of seeking into a 100mb file to write 1mb vs writing the whole 100mb?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

How efficient are HDDs or SSDs drives at overwriting the same data (same bytes)? I’m trying to decide if I should seek into a file location to update (not delete or change size) of one spot (updates one or more blocks on disk) or just write to the whole file from the memory contents. That is, if I seek to a spot in a 1 gig file and write to it, then close the file, does the whole file get overwritten, or only the part I changed? I was always under the impression that only a block would update, not the whole file. I'm pretty sure my impression is the answer, but decided to double-check.

Comment: Windows has little control over where data is stored on a traditional mechanical HDD or SSD.  It can defragment the file in the case of a mechanical HDD.  On a SSD it can TRIM the data, but the firmware of an SSD, has control over which literal cell will be used.  I am not sure I understand your "two options" from a technical point of view.  There is little difference to updating a file that already exists or overwriting the same file (that is how I interrupt your two options).

Comment: Further, SSD's cells have finite number of uses. For that reason, manufacturers desigm the SSD OS to *spread out* writes, rather reuse a block, causing early failure. "SSD drives are designed to scatter data around a SSD drive evenly to spread out the wear effect." https://sites.google.com/site/easytipsforlinux/solid-states-drives

Comment: You cannot *"seek into a file location to update one spot"*.  Mass storage drives are block devices.  A block (aka sector) must be read into memory, modified, and then the block can be written back.  The OS (or filesystem) will specify the block address (aka LBA).  But that is a *logical* address, and the drive's controller may (for HDD bad blocks, but always for SSD FTL) translate that *logical* address to a *physical* address. To speed up erase&write operations, the SSD will always remap the LBA to a new, different physical "sector" from the original, hopefully to a pre-erased "sector".

Comment: Thanks everyone. 1. I am aware that Windows has little control, should have not included that in the question. 2. I did forget that ssd drives don’t write to the same location, they move, but what about HDD? 3. I never said update a byte location. I’m aware of blocks and sectors. Are you saying updating one spot after seeking still updates the whole file on write, or just the block?

Comment: Consider this: **Storage is _linear_**. So if you change a 512-byte block in the middle of a file to a 511-byte block, all of the following blocks have to be rearranged/rewritten, because they are off by one byte. (If someone knows of a file-system that handles this better, please let me/us know).

Comment: I never said anything was deleted.  Obviously, having to shift file contents is a given. ;) Also, shifting a files is something I would have to do myself. Most languages where you seek into a file to write don't have a delete function for parts of a file, so I'd have to truncate it myself.

Comment: *"I never said update a byte location."* -- Seems like you don't know/remember what you yourself posted, and then misread what others wrote.  I have no idea how large or small an operation is when you *"update one spot"*.  And nobody but you wrote *"update a byte location."* --  *"I’m aware of blocks and sectors."* -- Yet in the post I responded to, you never use any of those technical words.  Instead you only mentioned *"bytes"* and *"spot"*.  -- *"Are you saying updating one spot after seeking still updates ..."* -- There you go again with that ambiguous, nontechnical *"spot"*!

Comment: *"How efficient are HDDs or SSDs drives at overwriting the same data..."* -- At the drive level there is no difference between a write and *"overwrite"*.  A write operation always ignores the old data, and that old data will be lost.  There is a special case for SSD, i.e. the LBA has no existing mapping to a physical "sector", but under normal/ideal conditions that should be irrelevant, i.e. there's a pool of available pre-erased "sectors".

Comment: *"does the whole file get overwritten, or only the part I changed?"*  -- You revised question cannot be answered, because it would depend on the OS, file type and the filesystem.

Comment: Updating one spot does not mean deleting it, just overwriting, which I assume was obvious, but I guess not.

Comment: @sawdust That's interesting, so if I seek into a 100mb file to overwrite 10 bytes, the OS determines if a block updates vs the whole file?  I never heard that before.

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking the wrong question, I think.

*Is making a small update to a large file faster than rewriting the whole file?* Yes, it absolutely is. It is faster on a HDD, it is faster on a SSD, it is faster on NTFS, it is also faster on a Copy-on-Write filesystem (not that Windows has any).

You can even update a single byte, because that is what the operating system APIs for reading and writing file data offer. The actual update may be larger due to filesystem block size (AKA cluster size) and storage device block size. Still, by writing only what actually needs to be written, you can ensure good performance.

Rewriting entire files could only be faster in very specific scenarios. If files are large (like the 1 GiB example you give) rewriting everything will be a lot slower.

What happens under the hood should be of no concern to you in most cases.

Comment: It is of concern in my case since I'm experimenting with a custom document database system of my own design, so an efficient storage system is important. I've updated the question to perhaps be a bit more clear.

Comment: It really isn’t though, unless you want to go for extreme performance optimization like batching to match filesystem and/or block device characteristics.

Comment: That did cross my mind, but I agree, these days that's a level of optimization that may not necessary for an initial design, or even possibly afterwards.